# Compact set in C(R^N)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Let $N\geq 1$, $M>m>0$, $k>0$ and $$S=\{u:\mathbb R^N\to (0, \infty), m(1+|x|)^{-k}\leq u(x)\leq M(1+|x|)^{-k}\}$$

Is it true that $S$ is a compact space in $C(\mathbb R^N)$ with the standard (norm) topology?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know of *a standard norm topology* on $C(\mathbb R^N)$. There is the stadand *Fréchet space topology* of uniform convergence on compact sets. In this topology, $S$ is not compact.

Comment: Let $\{u_n\}\subset S$. The sequence $\{u_n\mid_{B_1}\}$ is bounded in the supremum norm of the unit ball, so, it has a convergent subsequence $\{u_n^1\}$. Next, $\{u_n^1\}$ is bounded in the sup norm of $C(B_2)$ therefore, it has a convergent subsequence $\{u_n^2\}$ on $B_2$. Inductively, there exists $\{u_n^{m}\}\subset \{u_n^{m-1}\}$ which converges in $C(B_m)$. We look next at the diagonal sequence $\{u_n^n\}$ which converges to a certain $f:R^N\to R$ on any ball of $R^N$. Next, we claim that $\sup_{R^N}  |u_n^n-f|\to 0$.

Comment: @Marg No, in an infinite-dimensional Banach space a bounded sequence does **not** necessarily have a convergent subsequence.